# Prevent HTML Script element from running multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 to develop my app. Within `index.html` there are several scripts that will run at the start of the application.

I want to re-run `app.bundle.js` halfway when a user is using the app.

I have done something like this:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'build/js/app.bundle.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

In android, this works fine.

For iOS, after running this code, the app refreshes but my `console.log` shows multiple instances of each line. I am assuming the code starts a new cycle of the script but the original one is still running.

Anybody has any idea how to prevent this in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether you have multiple scripts running, you can do this:

`var viewScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");`

Let's say you wish to the first element, you can do this:

`viewScripts[0].parentElement.removeChild(b[0]);`

You can check if this prevents the multiple instances. Else it may be caused by another issue and not the scripts.

Comment: Tried removing the scripts but the issue still persisted. Thanks for the suggestion!